# Next page waiting for ajax to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Happening on chrome only. In firefox it is working fine

I have used this code:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/commonhelper/home/productscarousels",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (res) {
            jQuery(".prodCarousels").removeClass("loading-parent").html(res);
            jQuery( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();
        }
    });
```

When I go to the page and while it is loading and ajax is in the middle I click on any of the link on the page. The page will not go any further before getting response from the ajax which is sent.

By ajax [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) "Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.". Then why page is waiting for ajax getting response before going on next page?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Pls show full your code'

Comment: added my code. It is simple ajax I guess. but page is waiting for response

Comment: Are you sure only this ajax causing the issue? Are you getting an alert confirmation asking for "stay on page" or "leave page"? Ok, as recently edit and wrote about chrome, so firstly please check if there is any extension installed in chrome which is manipulating js files.

Comment: Yes, I am sure ajax response is the one loading the page, as when page html changed by ajax success then my request proceed to next page.

Comment: I have checked in different systems the result is the same